# Repeated temporary freezes

Tags: grub2, 18.04, kernel, freeze, lts

I am experiencing on my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS, some temporary freezes which last from 2 to 6 minutes. During this time period I can't do anything since mouse and keyboard are not responsive. The freezes are **always** temporary and happen **regularly** one each hour/an hour and half.

Given this periodically nature I have checked *cron*, but nothing relevant comes out.

Following some hints for fixing freeze issues I have modified the `/etc/default/grub` file adding the row `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=1"`, but this didn't help.

I am trying to analyze the `/var/log/kern.log` file, but I can't figure out anything. This [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KsspPcN9yp/) is a pastebin of the `kern.log` while I was experiencing one of the freezes.

Thanks in advance for anyone who is willing to help.

P.S.: `uname -a` output is `4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? You are having out of memory problems.

Comment: 4GB of RAM, but it happens also when I am doing anything like when I am searching on the file system or reading only a pdf

Comment: at least as a test, suggest you disable gsd-housekeeping. See [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1745666/comments/5) from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1745666).

Comment: It seems like my very same problem. Thank you, I will try and I will upload the thread if something happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doug Smythies comment contains the link to the workaround that solves the problem.

I leave you a summary:

> 1. `sudo mv /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-housekeeping /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-housekeeping.off`
> 2. logout and login

More info on the link, follow it if this workaround doesn't work for you!